# Auto Completar formulario AJAX, PHP7, JQuery, JSON

Tags: javascript, html5, ajax, array, php7

Tengo este arreglo que obtengo de una consulta de una función:

```
[{"Response":"correct","Curp":"ROPL910407HCHDRS08","DatosFiscales":{"Rfc":"ROPL910407I68","Comprobado":0,"Sncf":"","Subcontratacion":"-"},"Paterno":"RODRIGUEZ","Materno":"PARRA","Nombre":"LUIS CARLOS","Sexo":"H","FechaNacimiento":"1991-04-07","Nacionalidad":"MEX","DocProbatorio":"1","AnioReg":"1991","Foja":"0","Tomo":"0","Libro":"0","NumActa":"1911","CRIP":"","NumEntidadReg":"8","CveMunicipioReg":"19","NumRegExtranjeros":"","FolioCarta":"","CveEntidadEmisora":"","StatusCurp":"RCN"}]
```

Estos datos los obtengo de esta **función** que recibe un valor **CURP**:

```
 public function curp($curp)
    {
        $curl = curl_init();

        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => "https://conectame.ddns.net/rest/api.php?m=curp&user=prueba&pass=sC%7D9pW1Q%5Dc&val=$curp",
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
            CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                "Postman-Token: 0e16505a-b25e-4e31-9b6a-d00fa67b223e",
                "cache-control: no-cache"
            ),
        ));

        $response = curl_exec($curl);
        $err = curl_error($curl);

        curl_close($curl);

        if ($err) {
            echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
        } else {
            return json_encode($response);
        }
    }
```

Aquí es donde por metodo **POST** obtengo el *dato de entrada* utilizando **Postman** para hacer la consulta e imprimir el resultado. Bueno todo bien hasta aquí.

```
 case 'consultarcurp':
        $rspta=$usuarios->curp($curp);
        
      
        //Decodificamos para extraer el array
        $decode = json_decode($rspta, true);
          $json= '['.$decode.']';
          echo $json;
        
        break;
```

Ahora quiero utilizar un formulario donde pueda introducir la **CURP** y autocomplete los campos faltantes.

**Ejemplo del formulario**

[image: Formulario]

Con **JavaScript** quiero sacar los datos obtenidos de la consulta en **AJAX** para autocompletar los cuadros de texto en el formulario, pero no logro recorrer el arreglo. Pongo ejemplo del archivo **JavaScript** :

```
    function mostrarcurp(curp)
{
    $.post("../ajax/usuarios.php?op=consultarcurp",{curp : curp}, function(data, status)
    {
        
        data = JSON.parse(data);        
        
         
         $("#Paterno").val(data.Paterno);
         $("#Materno").val(data.Materno);
         $("#Nombre").val(data.Nombre);
         $("#Sexo").val(data.Sexo);
         $("#FechaNacimiento").val(data.FechaNacimiento);
         $("#Nacionalidad").val(data.Nacionalidad);
     });
}
```

Comment: Saludos, Creo te falto indicar la duda. Así como falta si ese arreglo lo recibes en JavaScript y de ahi lo quires vaciar o esta en PHP; claro igual el código de lo que tienes en cualquiera de los casos y cual es el obstáculo que presentas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estás recibiendo un arreglo con un solo elemento (cero) y debes verificar que la respuesta (*Response*) es correcta antes de acceder a los datos con `data[0].NombreDePropiedad`:

```js
const datos = '[{"Response":"correct","Curp":"ROPL910407HCHDRS08","DatosFiscales":{"Rfc":"ROPL910407I68","Comprobado":0,"Sncf":"","Subcontratacion":"-"},"Paterno":"RODRIGUEZ","Materno":"PARRA","Nombre":"LUIS CARLOS","Sexo":"H","FechaNacimiento":"1991-04-07","Nacionalidad":"MEX","DocProbatorio":"1","AnioReg":"1991","Foja":"0","Tomo":"0","Libro":"0","NumActa":"1911","CRIP":"","NumEntidadReg":"8","CveMunicipioReg":"19","NumRegExtranjeros":"","FolioCarta":"","CveEntidadEmisora":"","StatusCurp":"RCN"}]';

let data = JSON.parse(datos);
// Verificar que es un array, existe el elemento cero y la respuesta es correcta
if(data[0] && data[0].Response == 'correct') {
         $("#Paterno").val(data[0].Paterno);
         $("#Materno").val(data[0].Materno);
         $("#Nombre").val(data[0].Nombre);
         $("#Sexo").val(data[0].Sexo);
         $("#FechaNacimiento").val(data[0].FechaNacimiento);
         $("#Nacionalidad").val(data[0].Nacionalidad);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="Paterno">
<input type="text" id="Materno">
<input type="text" id="Nombre">
<input type="text" id="Sexo">
<input type="text" id="FechaNacimiento">
<input type="text" id="Nacionalidad">
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!!! @Triby esa es lo que estaba buscando! te lo agradezco mucho!! Saludos!!